# Not understanding promise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-promise

I thought I was doing well with AngularJS & REST until I came across a problem where my data service was not returning data back in time for my model to use it.

So, I have looked at and implemented a promise, but it is still not delaying until the HTTP REST call is done.

I would appreciate any help from the enlightened.

My routing passes a booking Id to the bookingController, which retrieves the booking details and then displays them in an editable form in booking.html template.

```
testLabApp.controller('bookingController', function ($q, $scope, $location, $window, $routeParams, service) {
if ($routeParams.id) {
    $scope.bId = $routeParams.id;

    //Expected this to setup my promise
    var bookdefer = $q.defer();
    bookdefer.promise
        .then(function (booking) {

            //When successful the result is assigned to my booking in the controller $scope
            $scope.booking = booking;

            //I am making a copy for form updates
            $scope.editableBooking = angular.copy($scope.booking);

            //When it runs console displays error:-
            // "TypeError: Unable to get property 'Storeno' of undefined or null reference"
            console.log("[bookingCtrl] 1 New: " + $scope.booking.Storeno + " and Editable: " + $scope.editableBooking.Storeno);
        });

    // Is this not calling my getBooking service function with the Id passed into my controller?
    bookdefer.resolve(service.getBooking($scope.bookingId));

}
else {
    //...
}
```

When code get to '[bookingCtrl] 1...' the console displays an error "TypeError: Unable to get property 'Storeno' of undefined or null reference", which makes me think that the booking data hasn't been retrieved.

then after this message the console displays:

```
[getBooking] Done = Id: 209 | Store no: 9180 | Description: test | Status: Booked
```

My data service includes a number of functions which make REST calls:-

```
testLabApp.factory('service', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    var service = {};

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Bookings')/Items?$filter=Id eq '" + bookingId + "'",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
        },
    }).success(function (d) {
        var e = d.d.results[0];
        booking = {
            Id: e['Id'],
            Storeno: e['Title'],
            BookedBy: e['BookedBy'],
            Description: e['Description'],
            StartDate: e['StartDate'],
            EndDate: e['EndDate'],
            Status: e['Status']
        };
        console.log("[getBooking] Done = Id: " + booking.Id + " | Store no: " + booking.Storeno + " | Description: " + booking.Description + " | Status: " + booking.Status);

        return booking;

    }).error(function (er) {
        console.log("[getBooking] http error : " + er);
    });
};
```

Thanks again for any helps or suggestions.

Regards
Craig

Answer (score 2):

The success function in your service is executed asynchronously. As a consequence, your service actually returns null to your controller. Here's what I've done in all my angular projects:

```
service.getStuff = function(id) {
    var dfd = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/some-end-point/id'
    }).then(function(data) {
        var result = data.data;
        dfd.resolve(result);
    }, function(error) {
        $log.error(error);
        dfd.reject(error);
    });
    return dfd.promise;
}
```

And my controllers are written like this:

```
if ($routeParams.id) {
    $scope.bId = $routeParams.id;

    //Expected this to setup my promise
    service.getStuff($routeParams.id).then(
        function(data){
            $scope.booking = data;
        },
        function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This solution works, however you don't actually need to create/return a new deferred object. You can actually just return your $http call, and then also return inside the .success and .error functions

Comment: True. But I often do some initialization on my services and my controllers don't really need to know about that. It's a matter of preference, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Andre - I couldn't get it to work. Still got .then undefined error.

Answer (score 1):

'Below is an example of an asynchronous get call from a controller using a service. You can actually return $http.get() to your controller in order to not need to create a new deferred object:

```
(function(){

  angular.module('app', []);


  angular.module('app').factory('service', ['$http', function($http){

    return {
      getData: getData;
    }

    function getData(){
      return $http.get('/url')
        .success(function(data){
          //Do business logic here
          return data;
        })
        .error(function(error){
          return error;
        });
    }

  }]);

  angular.module('app').controller('controller', ['$scope', 'service',  function($scope, service){

    service.getData()
      .success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
      })
      .error(function(error){
        //error logic
      });
  }]);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks @ajliptak - Can I still do my processing of the results data between `.success(function(data) {` and `return data` or is that for the controller to handle?  e.g. create an array from data and return that?

Comment: You can and should do that logic in the factory.

Comment: Hi again @ajliptak - I've defined my factory as `testLabApp.factory('service', [ '$http', function($http) {
    return { getBooking: getBooking;}` and get an error, expecting '}'. Do I need to follow the exact syntax as above?

Comment: Sorry @ajliptak - one more question please - why is there a `return $http.get`? What is it returning and where to? Cheers, C.

Comment: Hi Craig, to answer your first question, you are missing a } and a ] and a ). The syntax I used is best practice, but you don't have to follow it if you don't want to. Returning $http.get is actually returning a promise (basically a deferred) so you don't have to create a new one.